# Term to describe an individual with skill level beyond expert, possessing abilities that should not be used conventionally in their field of expertise

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing an instruction for using some software at my work, and have a somewhat tongue-in-cheek section that covers techniques that should only be used in the most dire of circumstances when there is absolutely no other way to produce a result.

I have an *"Expert-Level Techniques"* section already, and am trying to find a good word to replace "expert" in this tongue-in-cheek section that does justice to the type of techniques being described. These are techniques that would be frowned upon by other experts in the field, but can deliver results in the most dire of times.

Originally I considered "God-Mode" (referring to the similar usage in many video games for when you cheat) and I've had "Black-magic", "witchcraft" and "Voodoo" suggested to me, but I want to avoid using a word that might be seen to reference race or religion.

Single or compound words, or phrases would be fine in this circumstance.

Comment: How about “Black ops” - the kind of activities that have to be undertaken but nobody wants to admit they do.

Comment: _Maverick_ might fit nicely. Suggests not "playing playing by the rules".

Comment: Similar to _Black Ops_ would be _Dark Arts_.

Comment: master, quite simply: a master magician, a master coder

Comment: Great suggestions, @SteveLovell I will go with Maverick if you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several great options were put forward that I would be happy to use, however I've decided to go with:

> ***[Maverick](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/maverick)***:
>
> someone who exhinits great indpendence in thought and action.
>
> [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/maverick)

As per the comment provided by @Stevelovell. Thanks to all for the great input and suggestions. Thanks for such a positive experience with my first English Language & Usage question!

Comment: Glad this works for you. I didn't see your comment until late, so I'm happy for you to accept your own answer. It would be good to also add at least definition of the word, which I'll suggest as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Virtuoso might be tongue-in-cheek enough?

[Virtuoso](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/virtuoso): a person who is extremely skilled at something, especially at playing an instrument or performing.

Comment: Thanks Ashley very nice suggestion, I will keep it in mind! However, I'm looking for something that better captures the idea that other experts would reject the idea of using the kind of skills that this individual would possess. Kind of like an 'evil-genius' without the malevolency

Answer (score 2):

How about "**emergency** techniques"? From Lexico:

> **[emergency](https://www.lexico.com/definition/emergency)**: Arising from or used in an emergency.

One could characterize the direst of times or circumstances as an emergency. One could also say "**use-only-in-case-emergency** techniques", or, related, "**when-all-else-fails**" techniques.

"**Hail Mary** techniques" is also a possibility. From Wiktionary:

> **[Hail Mary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass)** (pass) : An act done in desperation, with only a very small chance of success.

This would fit well in a "tongue in cheek" section.

Answer (score 1):

For something beyond *expert*, but rejected because it puts the person beyond a normally accepted playing field in a way that is almost like cheating, consider **[unnatural](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unnatural)**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : not being in accordance with nature or consistent with a normal course of events
>    //  She has an *unnatural* obsession with money.

So:

> Expert-Level Techniques
> *Unnatural* Techniques (Abilities)

---

A similar word is [**uncanny**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncanny):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : seeming to have a supernatural character or origin : EERIE, MYSTERIOUS
> **1 b** : being beyond what is normal or expected : suggesting superhuman or supernatural powers
>        // an uncanny sense of direction

I don't personally think this works as well as *unnatural*, but I provide it as an alternative or for the purpose of comparison.

I'll note that I also don't know the details of the software being documented, so it could actually fit in that specific context in a way that it wouldn't in general.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate word is probably "high risk" - since it reinforces what is really at the nub of why these techniques are not routinely used.

Suggesting the techniques are merely mystical ("voodoo", "dark arts") or that they require a high degree of expertise ("black ops", "god mode") will likely only glorify them and induce people (who already usually consider themselves to be the technical or intellectual elite) to use them more frequently than intended. Meanwhile, your intention appears to be the opposite - to deter their use in all but exceptional circumstances when it represents the last possible option.

It may be appropriate to discuss what the risks are, how they can be mitigated, and what the required remedies are if those risks materialise. This is likely to be valuable to a reader of an instruction manual.

It may also be appropriate to discuss what level of authority is required, or what level of sanction will follow for improper use. If you are a software provider to external clients, you may also wish to consult lawyers if you are suggesting something that would be "frowned upon by experts".

Comment: Very good comment@ Steve. I didn't want to get too esoteric and off topic explaining what we're doing with the software, but I probably should taken more effort to explain that the risks surrounding the use of these techniques are very low. Maybe a good analogy is making an image composite in MS Paint and Publisher instead of using a professional editor suite like Photoshop- the result could very well end up looking the same but the process to get there would be very different, and most graphic design experts would probably scoff at the compromise (-maybe, I'm not an expert!)

Comment: After considering what you've said, I think I will definitely make sure to explain the potential consequences and pitfalls of the techniques I discuss. Just because it it tongue-in-cheek doesn't mean it shouldn't be well explained. Thanks again for your input

Comment: @Rorxor, ah I see. The risk is of terribly low aesthetic quality, and of experts scoffing at such quality. If necessary to keep up the tongue-in-cheek tone, you could call it the "cowboy corner", the "last chance saloon", or something, but definitely do not compromise on explaining the problem and the compromises that may result.

Answer (score 0):

How about "The One"? I'm thinking, like Neo in [The Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_(The_Matrix)) - an individual who against all odds was able to transcend the restrictions of the world of the Matrix.

> I'm trying to free your mind, Neo. But I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it. -- Morpheus

Answer (score 0):

I am just a layman who came across your question, but what about *unbelievable*? I think it might be a good word to use. Hope it helps. :D